# jQuery - Bootstrap message to show only when new items are PUT

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a client list page that displays all clients using an AJAX request. I'm trying to show a Bootstrap message that will only appear when a new client is added to the list.

So, essentially, I only want the message to appear if a new record is added.

HTML (some handlebars here too):

```
<div id="message" class="hide">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert-success">&times;</a>
  <div id="message_content"></div>
</div>
<div id="pageDiv{{index}}" class="btn-group">
  <div class="accountName">
  <a href="dashboard.html?client={{name}}" class="btn btn-default templateLink">{{name}}&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
  $('#message').removeClass('hide').addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible').slideDown().show();
  $('#message_content').html('<b>Success!</b> Client has been created.');
});
```

Obviously, the current jQuery has this message load on every page refresh since it's successfully making an AJAX PUT every time. Can't figure out how to make it only load when new records are added.

Comment: How do you add the records?

Comment: using a form and an ajax POST to the database

Comment: Return a success code in your response when the record is successfully added to the database, and check for it in your ajax method?